# Changing ownership of an object does not give permissions to the new owner

Tags: plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

My application automatically creates contents when an object's workflow state is changed. But this new content is created with the user changing the state as the owner. I would like to give ownership to another user. The new user is indeed owner, but he doesn't have the permission to edit the content. It is a custom dexterity content type.

I tried this:

```
company.changeOwnership(mtool.getMemberById(context.username))
company.manage_setLocalRoles(context.username, ['Owner'])
company.setCreators([context.username])
company.reindexObjectSecurity()
```

Is something missing ? The only information I found was this [script](http://www.uwosh.edu/ploneprojects/docs/how-tos/scripts-to-change-owner-of-an-item), but the creator said he had to set the permissions using the @@sharing view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The parent folder was internally published and thus the object, having no workflow, acquired the folder. Which means it couldn't be modified.